# What is the right strategy for permissions for /var/www directory?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

It looks very tricky as I need to access this directory to create and edit files (not as root of course), besides PHP scripts will probably also need to modify the directory: create new subfolders, new files, edit files and so on...

Which users and groups should be created? which owners and groups should be designated to the folder? And which permissions should be assigned to the folder?

Comment: Setup multiple folders.  For the most secure installation, the folder which webapps store their data in will be completely separate from the folders that have executable content.

Comment: @Zoredache that's a good hint! Thanks! But how about rights codes and directories belonging?